# Is it possible overriding a global implemented function?

Tags: c++

I'm being curious about if it is possible to override an implemented function. 
I mean, is there any legal syntax of function declaration / implementation that allows alternative implementation?
Why am I asking? (I know it sounds ridiculus)
First, just of curiosity and expanding my knowledge.
Second, I've learned that the global `new` can be overrided (Although it is strongly not recommended).
Third, assume that I have written a library: `AwsomeLibrary.hpp`, which
my friend wants to include.
Among a lot of functions, there is a function like `void sort(int* arr)`, which he thinks that he could implement better (and of course call it with the same name).

Comment: You can't provide more than one definition for a function. See the [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). You also can't "undefine" a defined function, at least not through any standard mechanism. For overloading global `new`, it's most common use (in my experience) is to implement diagnostic tools to track memory allocations and is not generally used in production code.

Comment: The global `operator new` can be overriden as long as no other definition exists in your program (including libraries). That doesn't mean you could provide more than one definition for the same function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean, is there any legal syntax of function declaration /
>   implementation that allows alternative implementation?

No. That would break the one-definition rule (ODR).

> Second, I've learned that the global `new` can be overrided (Although
>   it is strongly not recommended).

*Replaceable allocation functions* as documented at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new are really just a very special case, a grey area between language and standard library; certainly not something from which you can infer general rules for your own code.

> Third, assume that I have written a library: AwsomeLibrary.hpp, which
>   my friend wants to include. Among a lot of functions, there is a
>   function like void sort(int* arr), which he thinks that he could
>   implement better (and of course call it with the same name).

Such problems are beyond the scope of C++. They are more related to source control versioning systems like [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git). If, for example, your project is under Git control, then your friend could create a branch of the code with his better implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible at language level, aside from one "bizarre" language feature you mentioned yourself: replaceable `operator new` and `operator delete` functions. These functions can be replaced through a dedicated mechanism, which is why it is formally referred to as *replacement* (as opposed to *overriding* or *overloading*). This feature is not available to the language user for their own functions.

Outside the limits of standard language you can employ such implementation-specific features as *weak symbols*, which would allow you to create replaceable functions. For example, virtually all functions in GNU standard C library are declared as weak symbols and can be replaced with user-provided implementations.

The latter is exactly what would facilitate replacement of `void sort(int* arr)` function in your library. However this does not look like a good design for a library. Function replacement capability should probably reserved for debugging/logging and for other internal library-tuning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no.  It would be nice if the "override" directive would work on global functions.  But there are two ways around it.

Method #1: defines
You can define a symbol to be the name of the function to use.

```
#ifndef MY_SORT
#define MY_SORT qsort
#endif

MY_SORT(base, num, size);
```

Then you can override MY_SORT with compiler switches.

Method #2: function pointer
You can maintain a global pointer to the function that should be used.

```
void (*sort_function_ptr)(void *, int, int) = qsort;

void my_sort(void *p, int num, int size)
{
sort_function_ptr(p, num, size);
}

void my_sort_override(void (*f)(void *, int, int))
{
sort_function_ptr = f;
}
```

Now your program can call my_sort_override() if it decides to use a different function.  Everywhere sorting is performed should call my_sort().